# Adding controller buttons to prompt text?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, controller

I want to make a controller button prompt in my game where it says 'Press X to Join', but I want the X to be an actual graphic of the 'X' button, like how it is in many games. How would I go about doing that? Right now I'm just putting a big space in my prompt text and putting a UI Image of the button in it, but I want to know if there's a better way about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of scaling to different resolution sizes, you would wanna scale the anchors of the UI elements correctly and have an appropriate parent-child relation tree in Unity's hierarchy.

[image: Example hierarchy]

The red box is the hierarchy.
The 2 green boxes shows ways of scaling the anchors.
The orange box shows the end result of it.

Anchors in combination with their relative position, allows Unity's UI elements to scale up and down according to screen size.

So for example if you say that an anchor is at 0.25x, that would be that its anchored at 25% of for example the x axis. Same goes if you set it for the y axis, just the vertical instead of horizontal anchoring.

You can use the anchors to adjust a minimum and a maximum anchor which the elements may float within, they may have the same value as well, then it's a fixed anchor point.

To clarify, I suggest that you use a panel to hold 2 text elements and the image with the X, each text element being on the left and right side of the X instead of having spacing inside the UI text elements. To keep correct spacing you then must use anchor points. This way your spacing stays correct despite changing screen and resolution sizes.

Please note that the "left", "top", "right" and "bottom" values are then relative to the anchor points. So if you move "left" 5 pixels, those 5 pixels will be out from the relative anchor point.

Here's the values I used:

- My left text is at 0.25x, right text is at 0.8x, image is at 0.5x.
- The panel holding the 3 is at 0.2 minimum x to 0.8 max x, same goes for y axis.
- The largest parent panel is stretched to max fit in the canvas.